# Vue.js: passing class to nested tag in component

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

How do I insert a class into a component class tag from the HTML file. For example, if I have a component as below and I would like to have the `icon` field replaced by whatever I use in the html file.

MyButton.vue file:

```
<template>
  <component :is="type" :href="href" class="button btn">
      <i class="fa fa-lg" :class="[icon]"></i>
  </component>
</template>


<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      href: {
        type: String,
        default: null
      },
      to: {
        type: String,
        default: null
      },
      icon: {
        type: String,
        default: null
      }
    },
    computed: {
      type() {
        if (this.href) {
          return 'a'
        } else {
          return 'button'
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

app.js

```
Vue.component('my-button', require('./components/MyButton.vue').default);
```

html file:

```
<my-button class="fa-save"></my-button>
```

My required output would be something equivalent to:

```
<a type="button" class='button btn'><i class="fa fa-lg fa-close "></i></a>
```

Comment: Would you not simply pass the `icon` prop, eg `<my-button icon="fa-close"/>`?

Comment: @Phil does not seem to work

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @Sphinx no error. it just does not render anything

Comment: open the browser console, what is the rendered Dom for `<my-button>`?

Comment: <button class="button btn"><i class="fa fa-lg">::before</i></button>

Comment: Works for me ~ https://jsfiddle.net/p9whL5oy/

Comment: did you save the changes? hot reload already finished? if yes, refresh the web page then check again.

Comment: I dont know what is going on but all saved and refreshed.

Comment: managed to rebuild everything and the solution worked. Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly bind props to html attributes.

In MyButton.vue:

```
<i class="fa fa-lg" :class="[icon]"></i>
```

Or you can just pass `icon` as a string.

```
<i class="fa fa-lg" :class="icon"></i>
```

Then, you would have to pass the props to your component caller.

```
<my-button icon="fa-close"></my-button>
```

Comment: Thank you @Sphinx. Just realized that.

Comment: What did you realise? There was nothing wrong with your previous version with `:icon="icon"` ~ https://jsfiddle.net/6jop398a/

Comment: class could accept an array, vue will compile it to a space separated string.

Comment: But the prop is a string 

Comment: @Phil, even `prop=icon` is one string, but both `<i class="fa fa-lg" :class="icon"></i>` and  `<i class="fa fa-lg" :class="[icon]"></i>` are correct. we don't know the context for the use case, probably the Op want to pass multiple classes into `prop=icon`. probably the Op want to combine two classes like `:class="[icon, innerClasses]"` (assuming `innerClasses` is one data/computed property.

Comment: @Phil Hah, my bad if so. 